# Understanding Trie Tree Implementation in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, algorithm, data-structures, trie

Please I don't understand the logic in the **add** and **search** method here, can someone help me explain what's going on in these methods, especially in the two **while loops** inside **add()**. I encountered this in the book *Hands-On Data Structures and Algorithms with JavaScript by Kashyap Mukkamala*. Also I want to understand how this implementation is related to a trie tree, possibly suggest a more simpler implementation of this same logic.

```js
 
export class Trie {
    tree: any = {};

    constructor() {}

    add(input) {
        // set to root of tree
        var currentNode = this.tree;

        // init value
        var nextNode = null;

        // take 1st char and trim input
        var curChar = input.slice(0,1);
        input = input.slice(1);

        // find first new character, until then keep triming input
        while(currentNode[curChar] && curChar){
            currentNode = currentNode[curChar];

            // update remainder array, this will exist as we added the node earlier
            currentNode.remainder.push(input);

            // trim input
            curChar = input.slice(0,1);
            input = input.slice(1);
        }

        // while next character is available keep adding new branches and prune till end
        while(curChar) {
            // new reference in each loop
            // create remainder array starting with current input
            // so when adding the node `a` we add to the remainder `dam` and so on
            nextNode = {
                remainder: [input]
            };

            // assign to current tree node
            currentNode[curChar] = nextNode;

            // hold reference for next loop
            currentNode = nextNode;

            // prepare for next iteration
            curChar = input.slice(0,1);
            input = input.slice(1);
        }
    }

    search(input) {
        // get the whole tree
        var currentNode = this.tree;
        var curChar = input.slice(0,1);

        // take first character
        input = input.slice(1);

        // keep extracting the subtree based on the current character
        while(currentNode[curChar] && curChar){
            currentNode = currentNode[curChar];
            curChar = input.slice(0,1);
            input = input.slice(1);
        }

        // reached the end and no subtree found
        // i.e. no data found
        if (curChar && !currentNode[curChar]) {
            return {
                remainder: []
            };
        }

        // return the node found
        return currentNode;
    }
}
```

Comment: So what part *do* you understand, and where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: @Bergi the logic in the two while loops in add() is not quite clear to me, also that of search

Comment: is that really the code from the book? I thought any experienced programmer would reverse `currentNode[curChar] && curChar`

Answer (score 0):

The main difference with usual `trie` implementations is the use of `remainder` here.

For words `adam` and `adx`, a common trie would look like

```
a -> d -> a -> m
     | -> x
```

In this implementation, the trie is also storing the "remaining" word in each node. So when you insert `"adx"` in an empty tree, it becomes

```
a (remainder: ["dx"]
|
d (remainder: ["x"]
|
x (remainder: []
|
null
```

Inserting `"adam"` in the same tree

```
a (remainder: ["dx", "dam"])
|
d (remainder: ["x", "am"])
|------------------------|
x (remainder: [])        a (remainder: ["m"])
|                        |
null                     m (remainder: [])
```

The search process is trivial though, it just search if the current node has the given character or not, and if it does, it continues the process on the child node iteratively.

Comment: Wait, they store an array of all remainders on every node? That's horribly space-inefficient, and also means that removal cannot be implemented in `O(log n)`

Comment: "so when adding the node `a` we add to the remainder `dam` and so on" is one of the comments in the code. Agreed, this is extremly inefficient and redundant